# React: sorting container by priority

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, sorting

I have the priority of displaying content:

```js
let priority = {
    coverPriority: 3,
    contentPriority: 1,
    contactPriority: 4,
    linksPriority: 2,
    teachersPriority: 5,
}
```

I want to sort the containers on the page:

```html
<div className="cover"> ... </div>
<div className="content"> ... </div>
<div className="contact"> ... </div>
<div className="links"> ... </div>
<div className="teacher"> ... </div>
```

What way do you suggest?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create an array of `containers` and sort it based on the `priority` object

```
const containers = ["cover", "content", "contact", "links", "teacher"];
containers.sort((a, b) => priority[a + "Priority"] - priority[b + "Priority"])
```

Then create `div`s based on the sorted array.

Here's a snippet:

```js
function Example({ priority }) {
  const containers = ["cover", "content", "contact", "links", "teacher"];

  return (
    <div>
      {containers
        .sort((a, b) => priority[a + "Priority"] - priority[b + "Priority"])
        .map(c => <div className={c} key={c}>{c}</div>)
      }
    </div>
  );
};

const priority = {
  coverPriority: 3,
  contentPriority: 1,
  contactPriority: 4,
  linksPriority: 2,
  teachersPriority: 5
};

ReactDOM.render(
  <Example priority={priority} />,
  document.getElementById("react")
);
```

```css
.cover { color: red }
.content { color: green }
.contact { color: blue }
.links { color: brown }
.teacher { color: purple }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id="react"></div>
```

Comment: Sorry for beginner's question: In your example how do I display data (html code and content) as `children` inside the containers?